# Java organize subclasses into different folders

Tags: java, eclipse, package, subclass, superclass

My problem is with Eclipse, something that seems super simple but I just don't know enough to figure out how to do it. I want to put the subclasses of the objects I have created into folders in the default package to organize them so I don't have dozens of objects jumbled together, but when I create a new folder in the Package Explorer and drop them in, they no longer connect to the superclasses. How do I connect them?

Comment: use `import` for access from subclass to superclass

Comment: so I imported the name of the superclass into the subclass, but that didn't work. How do import the whole default package?

Comment: Also, don't drag and drop; use the `move` option (right click the class). The `move` option updates all the references, so it should automatically do the imports for you.

Comment: I tried refactor->move, but it didn't add any imports.

Answer (score 2):

Create packages to organize your classes *not* folders.

Folders are created to store app resources, e.g., images and icons.

Right-click on your project's `src` node in the Package Explorer, then `New -> Other -> Package`.

Having created your packages and moved your classes under them, you should then organize the imports.

You do this by opening each class file and hitting the key combination `Ctrl+Shift+O`.

Comment: I created a new package, used refactor -> move, opened the first subclass I wanted to change, pressed 'Ctrl+Shift+O', but it says '0 import(s) added.'

Comment: If it says '0 import(s) added.' then it means that the current class doesn't need to import any other classes for it to function properly. Do you see any code errors in this class?

Comment: It can't be. If the superclass is located inside a package under `src`, then the Eclipse editor will import it (if needed) when you shoot `Ctrl+Shift+O`.

Comment: I tried moving it back and forth and it adds the import, but the import itself won't resolve.

Comment: and when I use 'Ctrl+Shift+O' it deletes the faulty import, leaving me with the 'extends' error

Comment: Exceptionally, try to add one import manually and see if the editor recognizes it properly. The editor may have hogged or something.

Comment: I erased the import and wrote it manually. It didn't change anything. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. "It didn't change anything", you mean that the imports you inserted manually aren't recognized as valid imports?